# Rspec - Account for Record with Specific ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model, Trip, that sets a default value for 'refund_policy' to the 'refund_policy' of that trip's company. Company in and of itself has a default value for it's 'refund_policy' to the policy of the Company with ID of 4.

My tests for a valid factory for Trip are failing, as are many others, because there is no Company with ID of 4 in the database. I have tried to set a company with the explicit ID. Also, my attempts to stub this company, or its refund policy, haven't worked yet.

All factories used are valid, as determined by prior tests.

I have tried:

```
#trip_spec.rb
describe Trip do
  let(:company) { FactoryGirl.build(:company) }
  let(:refund_policy) { 'example refund policy' }

  before do
    company.stub(:refund_policy).and_return(refund_policy)
    Company.stub(:find).and_return(company)
  end

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect( FactoryGirl.build :trip, company_id: company.id ).to be_valid
  end
end
```

I have also tried:

```
let(:company)       { FactoryGirl.build(:company, id: 4) }

it "has a valid factory" do
  expect( FactoryGirl.build :trip ).to be_valid
end
```

As well as:

```
let!(:company)       { FactoryGirl.create(:company, id: 4) }

it "has a valid factory" do
    expect( FactoryGirl.build :trip ).to be_valid
end
```

All result in this **error message**

```
# gives this error
Trip has a valid factory
  Failure/Error: let(:company) { FactoryGirl.build(:company) }
  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
    Couldn't find Company with id=4

 # ./app/models/company.rb:70:in `default_refund_policy'
 # ./app/models/company.rb:66:in `set_defaults'
 # ./spec/models/trip_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Default value for the trip refund_policy**

```
#trip.rb
def set_defaults
  self.refund_policy = company.refund_policy if company && (refund_policy.blank? || (refund_policy && refund_policy.strip.length == 0))
end
```

**Default value for the company refund_policy**

```
#company.rb
def set_defaults
  self.refund_policy = default_refund_policy if refund_policy.blank? || (refund_policy && refund_policy.strip.length == 0)
end

def default_refund_policy
  Company.find(4).refund_policy
end
```

How can I effectively account for this default value pathway?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `let!(:company) { FactoryGirl.create(:company, id: 4) }`

Comment: Just tried it. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are failing because `set_defaults` is called as part of the build process, which in turns calls `default_return_policy` which in turns calls `find`. With your production code as is, you'll need to stub `Company.find` prior to attempting to create a company.

In addition:

- Your second example wouldn't have worked because you're using `build` instead of `create`
- Your third example wouldn't have worked because you're using `let` instead of `let!` and not referencing the variable in your example.

The following should at least get your closer:

```
describe Trip do
  before do
    company = InstanceDouble(Company, refund_policy: 'example refund policy')
    Company.stub(:find).and_return(company)
  end

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect( FactoryGirl.build :trip, company_id: company.id ).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the issue is I need a company with ID of 4 before I can even create a new company.

Comment: Yes, this was the start of the right path, thank you. I switched 'InstanceDouble' to simply 'double', gave it an id of 4 and a refund policy, and voila!

Comment: I also updated your stub method to the current syntax: allow(Company).to receive(:find).and_return(company)